# Google maps GeoCode API doesn't return any result at all?

Tags: google-maps

This is weird. When I search something like "The New York Palace Hotel,America,New York" in Google maps app's search box I get exactly the hotel on the map.

However When I use the maps API,

A GET at `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=The%20New%20York%20Palace%20Hotel,America,New%20York&sensor=true`

I get ZERO results in the response.

It doesn't even give New York as the option in search results.

I am making an app where I use this API to get the lat-long for user provided address.

Now, I don't know why this Google maps API doesn't work the way the Google maps app works.

BUT I wanted to know, is there a way to search and provide Google maps API these search terms as meaningful words where instead of taking whole string as one parameter it knows which city I am searching and which Address I ams searching.

If not, then only option left with me will be to Once the first results fails I make another query for city name only.

Answer (score 0):

recently, i was given a similar task, and came to know `the api works reverse`... i.e.. we can get address for lat lon that we provide.. and that too has its own restrictions (i.e.. no.of addresses resolved per request, mostly some 2500 address per day something...)....[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) you can get some info over that...

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). "The New York Palace Hotel,America,New York" is not an address, it is a "place".  The [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) might be a better option.

[Example of your query using the (javascript version of) the Places API](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=The%20New%20York%20Palace%20Hotel,America,New%20York&place=1)

Comment: But I want the latitude and longitude of this place.
the example you have provided also fails if you click geocode button.

I don't want places near the lat-long, I want the lat-long of the place I have described and If I cant get that atleast a lat-long that represents the city on map.

Comment: As I said: "That isn't an address".  The geocoder _requires_ (for the most part) addresses.  "America, New York" is not an address either (although it does return [all the locations named "New York" in the US](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=America,%20New%20York&geocode=1)).  "New York" is an address and [will return the coordinates of the city](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=New%20York&geocode=1)

Comment: Even "The New York Palace, New York" Also doesn't work.
So isn't there a way for me to get coordinates for it? Any other API ?
"The Palace Hotel, EMEA, Sun City". This works though!

These are user entered addresses, I wont know what all will they provide.
Its coming form an API.

If GeoCOder can't find the exact place, it should atleast give me the city.

Comment: The thing is its an iOS app. I am using Google APIs to get coordinates  for the string I have and then giving these coordinates to Apple maps.

iOS sdk's gecoder service ain't as Good as this API.

Comment: That sounds like it is against the Terms of Use (results _must_ be displayed on a Google Map), but IANAL.